# How to import and use vue-good-table Vue component in a Laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, import, vue-component

I'm trying to import and use a Vue component called vue-good-table (https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/#installation) in a Laravel project but I can't get it to work. It does work if I import it in a normal Vue Project, but not with Laravel. 
I installed the component with npm and tried to import it as described several times. How would you import it? (the ideal for me would be to import it globally).

Where and how do I have to import the component?

My basic files are the following:

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap'); 
window.Vue = require('vue'); 
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**MyTable.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-good-table
      :columns="columns"
      :rows="rows"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-table',
  data(){
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          label: 'Name',
          field: 'name',
        },
        {
          label: 'Age',
          field: 'age',
          type: 'number',
        },
        {
          label: 'Created On',
          field: 'createdAt',
          type: 'date',
          dateInputFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
          dateOutputFormat: 'MMM Do yy',
        },
        {
          label: 'Percent',
          field: 'score',
          type: 'percentage',
        },
      ],
      rows: [
        { id:1, name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '',score: 0.03343 },
        { id:2, name:"Jane", age: 24, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**vuegoodtable.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue comp test  </title>
    <script src="/js/app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <my-table> </my-table>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: "_I got some kind of error_" What kind of error would that be? "_How would you import it?_" I'd follow the installation instructions. From that installation page, place the code below "_Import globally in app_" in your `resources/js/app.js` - and that should be it

Comment: For example it gives me the error: **Unknown custom element: <my-table> - did you register the component correctly?**  I tried to follow the instructions

Comment: So, did you register your own `MyTable` component? In `app.js`? Like that `ExampleComponent` that comes with Laravel?

Comment: Alright it works! Sorry, I just started with Vue, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it works ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can install using npm and import easily

Install with npm:

```
npm install --save vue-good-table
```

Import globally in app:

```
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table';
```

// import the styles

```
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css'

Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
```

Import into your component

```
import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table';
```

// add to component

```
components: {
  VueGoodTable,
}
```

Import into your component using Typescript

// add to component
components: {

```
  'vue-good-table': require('vue-good-table').VueGoodTable,
}
```

for more info https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table